# std::array of size zero

Tags: c++, stdarray

What does it mean to have `std::array<int,0>`,array of size zero?

I have gone through similar questions in SO before posting this, and all those
questions are regarding simple array type and for C language and most of them says that it is illegal. But in C++ `array<int,0>` is allowed.

As per cppreference.com

> There is a special case for a zero-length array (N == 0). In that case, `array.begin() == array.end()`, which is some unique value. The effect of calling `front()` or `back()` on a zero-sized array is undefined.

Why isn't it defined as illegal?

Comment: Because templated code can take advantage from something like this.

Comment: Why should it be illegal? I'd be rather annoyed if I had to add special cases to my code to avoid a zero-sized array, rather than letting `array` handle that case in the obvious way.

Comment: @MikeSeymour `int x[0];` *is* illegal. I guess the question is why the difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> What does it mean to have std::array,array of size zero?

The same as for example an empty `std::vector` or an empty `std::set`.

> Why isn't it defined as illegal?

It is ***desirable*** to make it legal because it means generic programming does not have to handle a special case when the `std::array`'s size is the result of a compile-time calculation.

It is ***possible*** to define it as legal thanks to template specialisation. For example, the implementation that comes with Visual C++ specialises `std::array` in a fashion similar to the following:

```
template<class T>
class array<T, 0> // specialisation
{
    // ...

    size_type size() const
    {
        return 0;
    }

    T elements[1]; // the raw array cannot have a size of 0
};
```

I suppose every compiler implements `std::array` like that.

Comment: template specialization like that? What needless duplication, we have the conditional operator for that.

Comment: That's a rather surprising implementation. Default constructing a `T` when I ask for an array of zero `T` is...odd.

Comment: Hmm, libc++ does the same thing. libstdc++ doesn't, but then arguably invokes UB in their handling of `begin()` etc. for zero-sized arrays.

Comment: @T.C: `begin()` is undefined behaviour for zero-sized `std::array`s, anyway.

Comment: Whoops, it's not, of course. I meant `front`. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Deduplicator: `boost::array` apparently also does this via template specialisation (at least in 1.57.0), although it does not have a raw array member variable.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Strange enough, the VC header does *also* use the conditional operator in the non-specialised template: `_Ty _Elems[_Size == 0 ? 1 : _Size];`. I wonder why, though. In presence of the specialisation for 0, `_Size` can never be 0 there.

Comment: Summarizing http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#2157: It is legal, but default-construction of `std::array<T, 0>` must be possible for all `T`. The wording should be less subtle though.

Comment: This means you definitely can't use `std::array<void, 0>`, right? And are there no wacky overlaps between `std::array<int,0>` and `std::array<Dog,0>`, etc.? In any case it seems to me like the logic breaks down even if `std::array<T, 0>` is supported. If you have a "nople" of anything, IMO you should not have to worry if your nothing is constructible, or how big your nothing is before you have anything, etc.

Comment: In libstdc++, `std::array<T, 0>` uses an empty struct (whose sizeof is 1) as its internal storage.  There is no `T` constructed.

Answer (score 2):

std::array is considered like other standard containers that can be empty. So the specialization of the `std::array` with N equal to zero defines an empty container.

Comment: But it's a little surprising because `std::array` encapsulates a C-style array, which is forbidden from having a size of zero.